# Consolidate records with min date and max date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two rows of data in a SQL Server query and need to consolidate them into one column by criteria of min date for one column and max date for the second column.

Example data:

```
OrderID   PrevCFS   NewCFS   ChangeTime
---------------------------------------------------
   1        75         25    2018-10-31 08:00:00
   2        25          0    2018-10-31 09:00:00
```

I need them to be combined using the earliest date for `PrevCFS` and the latest date for `NewCFS` as there could be more than two records:

Results:

```
PrevCFS   NewCFS   ChangeTime
---------------------------------------------------
  75        0      2018-10-31 09:00:00
```

The `OrderID` and Change time are not important in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the most recent columns by ordering descending, and the older columns by ordering ascending.

Here is one way to combine them:

```
select top (1) eprev.OldCFS, e.NewCFS, e.ChangeTime
from example e cross join
     (select top (1) e2.*
      from example e2
      order by e.ChangeTime asc
     ) eprev
order by e.ChangeTime desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `MAX` and `MIN` aggregate function.

```
SELECT MAX(PrevCFS) PrevCFS,
       MIN(NewCFS) NewCFS,
       MAX(ChangeTime) ChangeTime
FROM T
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful.?

```
    Declare @T Table(OrderId int,PrevCFS int, NewCFS int,ChangeTime DATETIME)

    Insert into @T
    SELECT 1,75,25,'2018-10-31 08:00:0' Union All
    SELECT 2,25,0,'2018-10-31 09:00:00'

    Select t1.PrevCFS,t2.NewCFS,t2.ChangeTime from @T t1
    INNER JOIN @T t2 on t1.NewCFS=t2.PrevCFS
```

output:

```
    PrevCFS    NewCFS           ChangeTime
------------------------------------------------
      75         0       2018-10-31 09:00:00.000
```